# Handle the status of JSON by Retrofit call

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I want to process JSON output from Rest call based on the status. So what will be the required approach?

Here is my method from RetrofitApi class

```
@POST("KeepHoldTisConfirmation")
Observable<ResultOutput> putHoldTis(@Body ResultOutput body);
```

Here is my MyObject class Structure

```
public int filterId;
public String type;
```

Here is my ResultOutput class Structure

```
public int status;
public List<MyObject> data;
```

If success my JSON output is:-

```
{"status":1,"data":[{"filterId":1,"type":"flower"},{"filterId":2,"type":"sand"}]}
```

If error my JSON output is:-

```
{"status":2,"data":"Invalid key"}
```

Here is my Observable code:-

```
Observable.fromIterable(entities)
                .filter(tisEntity -> "1".equals(tisEntity.isTisHold))
                .concatMapEager(tisEntity -> {
                    Log.d(TAG,"insert = "+tisEntity.hitachiCode);
                    return hitachiRetrofitApi.putHoldTis(new TisHoldEntity(tisEntity.projectId, tisEntity.holdReason, "76800",
                        tisEntity.holdComment,tisEntity.hitachiCode, 1));})
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ResultOutput>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ResultOutput responseBody) {
                        // handle here status and accordingly process output
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        cancleProgressDialog();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                        Log.d(TAG, "on complete for entity");
                        updateTisDetails();
                    }
                });
```

Here, what should I write inside onNext()?

Comment: what's the desired behavior? what is wrong with simple if at the onNext()? do you want to raise exceptions with error status?

Comment: I want ResultOutput as the desired json output, it is only possible when status is 1 if status is 2 it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can build a bean like this

```
classe Result {
    public int status;
    public String data;
}
```

First way parse the json from responseBody.body().string();

Second way make RetrofitApi class

```
@POST("KeepHoldTisConfirmation")
Observable<Result> putHoldTis(@Body ResultOutput body);
```

OnNext parse the Result.data.

Another way, make ConverterFactory class

```
public final class ConverterFactory<T> extends Converter.Factory {

  @Override
  public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
      final Retrofit retrofit) {
    return new Converter<ResponseBody, T>() {

      @Override
      public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String origin = value.string();

        try {
          Result response = JSON.parseObject(origin, Result.class);
          if (response.status == 1) {
              return JSON.parseObject(response.data, type);
          } else {
              throw new HttpException(Response.error(2, value));
          }
        } finally {
          value.close();
        }
      }
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

When build Retrofit add the Factory

```
new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(ConverterFactory.create());
```

Then you can handle the error in OnError()

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    if (e != null && e instanceof HttpException) {
       HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
       int code = exception.code();
       Response response = exception.response();
       String error = null;
       if (null != response && null != response.errorBody()) {       
           Result response = JSON.parseObject(origin, Result.class); 
           error = response.data  
       }
    }
}
```